# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)+openshift

Tags: cmd, server, cloud, openshift

i cant connect to my application on openshift using rhc command

here is what i get when trying to connect

```
 C:\Users\soulhiS>rhc ssh myapp
 DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
 RSA 1024 bit CA certificates are loaded due to old openssl compatibility
 Connecting to 56e736655650001b4@myapp-mydomain.rhcloud.com ...
 Using username "56e736655650001b4".
 FATAL ERROR: Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available(server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your ssh key is accessible (run the command line as administrator, if needed) and it is [the one OpenShift expects](https://developers.openshift.com/faq/troubleshooting.html#_why_am_i_getting_a_permission_denied_error) - i.e. check that a corresponding public key is uploaded to OpenShift. For uploading your public ssh key to OpenShift, you can [run `rhc setup`](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/client-tools.html#rhc-setup).